# Reorder the way in which scripts are run at startup

Tags: debian, init.d, lsb

I just moved to debian squeeze and need to change the startup sequence of some scripts.  I used to do this with `update-rc.d service defaulta xx xx` but now with the LSB way of doing things the `update-rc.d` method does not change the order.

I need to start the packages in this order:

- openvpn
- ndo2db
- nagios
- apache2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `Required-Start` keyword. For e.g, init script for `ndo2db` should have the following:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ndo2db
# Required-Start:    $openvpn
# Required-Stop:     $openvpn
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Daemonized ndo2db
# Description:       Starts the ndo2db daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

Take a look at [this](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) for more details.

Comment: What does one invoke to update the rcN.d-symlinks with the new values, though?

Comment: How about `dpkg-reconfigure insserv sysv-rc`: http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot

Comment: What about having apache2 load after openvpn.  I'm not sure that changing lsb scrpits for apache2 is a solution.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with patching the init-scripts.  It's like any other configuration file - you need to pay attention when you upgrade to a newer version, and apt will present you with a diff (because it detects that you've edited the file).  The same would apply if you were using upstart, and patching the upstart-configfiles.

Comment: I always thought that patching the init-scripts was a no-no.  Particularly in trying to keep maintainability going forward.  This is perhaps one of the reasons for having `/etc/default/*`.  Perhaps there is something similar for lsb scripts?

Comment: it should just be `openvpn`, without the `$`, btw

Answer (score 1):

Once you edit the Required-Start lines (and Required-Stop lines) in the appropriate files in your init.d directory, perform the following commands for each of the services you'd like reordered:

```
chkconfig --del servicename

chkconfig --add servicename
```

Once you do this, the init scripts will be reordered in your rc#.d directories.